# When should I use ZeroMQ and when should I use Akka?

Tags: multithreading, akka

My *understanding* of Akka is that it allows you to define groups of mini-threads ("**Actors**") and then have them communicate with each other (and do work) using events.

My *understanding* of ZeroMQ is that its a TCP socket library that allows threads to communicate with each other over TCP/ports.

My question: these seem like very similar concepts. However, I'm sure that in reality, they are meant to solve entirely different problems. So:

**Intention-wise, what is the difference between these two tools?** What different problems do they solve? Are there clear/concrete use cases where one is preferable to the other?

Comment: If you're interested in the model on which Akka is based, you can also take a look at Carl Hewitt's paper in 1973 and the wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Answer (score 3):

You're right, they are separate technologies.

[Akka](http://akka.io/) uses [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) under the covers.  From [their documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/zeromq.html):

> Akka provides a ZeroMQ module which abstracts a ZeroMQ connection and therefore allows interaction between Akka actors to take place over ZeroMQ connections.

Akka provides an implementation of the [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) whereas ZeroMQ is trying to avoid your having to implement a brokered Message Queue system of some sort.

Comment: Akka _can_ use ZeroMQ, but generally doesn't (please correct me if i'm wrong) for in-process actor-messaging.